# Get function from input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have some jQuery inside a text field which I need to fire, but I'm struggling to get anything to happen.

I think the best way to explain this is to put down some code:

```
<input type="hidden" id="win-body-tst" value="$("#a").append($("#b"));">

<script> function NNNfoo(){
  var funcvar = document.getElementById('win-body-tst').value;
  funcvar
}</script>
```

I am calling NNNfoo() successfully, but the append does not action.

Comment: Why are you trying to append an element to another element inside the `value` of yet another element? Also, JavaScript inside the `value` attribute isn't executed, all that'll give you is a string. Plus you're delimiting the strings *inside* the attribute with `"`, but the outer string is *also* delimited by `"` characters, so the string is opening and closing and forming invalid HTML.

Comment: Why are you including Javascript code as a hidden element in your form? This is a seriously bad idea. If you know what code to execute, just put it in your script. If there are alternatives, code them in your script and use a hidden field value to select between them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with

```
function NNNfoo(){
    var functionBody = document.getElementById('win-body-tst').value;
    var func = new Function( functionBody );
    func();
}
```

But why do you want to run arbitrary code from `input` elements ?

Comment: That's a rather long-winded way to do an `eval`.

Comment: i guess.. i have just completely erased `eval` from memory... :) although they are virtually the same... (*beside the scope issues*)

Comment: Thanks. I used this code with a global function to replace the input in the end. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

[`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) will run JS code which is expressed as a string (but I'd take a step back and try to solve whatever problem you have another way, it isn't usually a good idea to ask users to input JS).

```
eval(funcvar);
```

(You also need to convert your `"` as data to `&quot;` so that they don't act as attribute value delimiters).